# Automatic decimal number formatting in SQL or PHP?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

In my DB, most numeric values are of type DECIMAL(10,6). They are currency columns.

Now, when I retrieve the numbers from mysql, I get something like this

34.123456  //I want these
0.987654
500.000000 //I do not want these
1.000000

Is it possible to have the numbers automatically show up as integers when they are and to maintain decimals to my desired precision after the point, so that I get e.g.

34.123456
0.987654
500
1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is to modify the displayed digits, then you can use [printf](http://www.php.net/printf) with the `%g` formatter and specify maximum number of precision digits:

```
printf ("%.10g", 123.456); // outputs "123.456"
printf ("%.10g", 123.456000000); // outputs "123.456"
printf ("%.10g", 123.000000000); // outputs "123"
printf ("%.10g", 1.234567891); // outputs "1.234567891"
```

Comment: +1 for the subtle nudge to worry about formatting on the application layer, and to use a function that does *exactly* what's needed.

Comment: ...and then you have to employ the logic every time you want to display the value in a consistent format.  +1 for Maintenance nightmare

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you could do a simple integer comparison before output:

```
echo ((int) $var == $var) ? (int) $var : $var;
```

As a quick/dirty example, this code:

```
$var = '500.01';
echo ((int) $var == $var) ? (int) $var : $var;
echo "\n";
$var = '500.00';
echo ((int) $var == $var) ? (int) $var : $var;
```

Produces:

```
500.01
500
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `CAST` the value to whatever type you like to enforce this precision at the SQL side, for example:

```
SELECT 
  CASE myNumber MOD 1 
    WHEN 0 THEN CAST(myNumber AS decimal(10,0)) 
    ELSE myNumber 
  END 
FROM myTable;
```

Comment: I actually prefer this solution to having to cope with the maintenance issue, although I can see the value of that one. However, my mysql knowledge is really low, so can this be done for all tables just once, like a stored proc or so? Or do I have to even submit this code in my SQL statement inside the PHP file? Thanks

Comment: From the looks of things, you can't do this in a stored function because the return type is of two different precisions (a function should have only one specific precision which it returns).  There is nothing stopping you from putting this into a sProc, but you will have to call that sProc every time you want to massage the data in this way.